# A string doesn't work to select an element (with jquery) after using .replace() on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Both variable look the same, except one of them uses replace() and makes it not work.

```
<div id="h|1.1|Name!7">1.NOT CHANGED</div>
<div id="h|1.1|Title!7">2.NOT CHANGED</div>

var id = 'h|1.1|Name!7';

id = id.replace(/\./g,'\\\\.');
id = id.replace(/\|/g,'\\\\|');
id = id.replace(/\!/g,'\\\\!');

console.log(id); // all good

$("#" + id).text('1.CHANGED'); // not working

// when not using replace(), it works
var otherId = 'h\\|1\\.1\\|Title\\!7';
$("#" + otherId).text('2.CHANGED');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L83ba7zg/1/

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `\\\\` in your code should be just `\\`. The console output may *look* good, it’s wrong, though: The console displays only one backslash for every two backslashes. If you logged `otherId`, you’d get a different result.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L83ba7zg/3/)

```js
var id = 'h|1.1|Name!7',
  otherId = 'h\\|1\\.1\\|Title\\!7';

// More concise version of replacements:
id = id.replace(/(\.|\||\!)/g,'\\$1');

// Now in the same format:
console.log(id);      // "h\|1\.1\|Name\!7"
console.log(otherId); // "h\|1\.1\|Title\!7"
```